# How to convert a datatype of a column with both integer and decimal numbers in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, types

I was working on wine data on kaggle. Where there was a column named price has values like $32, $17, $15.99, Nan
`wine_data.isnull().sum()`--After applying this code, there were a lot of missing values so I wrote another code i.e.
`wine_data['designation'].fillna(wine_data['designation'].mode()[0], inplace = True)`
`wine_data['varietal'].fillna(wine_data['varietal'].mode()[0], inplace = True)`
`wine_data['appellation'].fillna(wine_data['appellation'].mode()[0], inplace = True)`
`wine_data['alcohol'].fillna(wine_data['alcohol'].mode()[0], inplace = True)`
`wine_data['price'].fillna(wine_data['price'].mode()[0], inplace = True)`
`wine_data['reviewer'].fillna(wine_data['reviewer'].mode()[0], inplace = True)`
`wine_data['review'].fillna(wine_data['review'].mode()[0], inplace = True)`

Then I wanted to do a correlation of alcohol with rating and price with rating but both alcohol and price column has '%' and '$' these characters.So, I applied this code.
`wine_data = wine_data.assign(alcohol_num = lambda row: row["alcohol"].replace("%", "", regex=True).astype('float'))`
`wine_data = wine_data.assign(price_numbers= wine_data['price'].str.replace('$','',regex = True)).astype('float')`

It's throwing me an error like--
could not convert string to float: 'J. Lohr 2000 Hilltop Vineyard Cabernet Sauvignon (Paso Robles)'

Then I tried this code:
`wine_data = wine_data.assign(price_numbers= wine_data['price'].str.replace('$','',regex = True)).astype('int')`
It's throwing me an error like--
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'J. Lohr 2000 Hilltop Vineyard Cabernet Sauvignon (Paso Robles)'

Comment: please format your question (follow the help on formatting), this is currently difficult to read

Comment: Be more precise with your question. Go to the point. Do you want to cast a given column to integers or to strings?

Comment: Come on, he obviosly wants to convert 'alc %' and 'price' to `numeric`.. (I have never seen anyone use `.astype('float')` to "correlate strings"..?!)

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not clean. One of the elements in your `price` column keeps containing the string `'J. Lohr 2000 Hilltop Vineyard Cabernet Sauvignon (Paso Robles)'`, which is why the column cannot be converted to `float`, even though you did some other cleansing steps.

You want be a bit more structured in your data cleansing: Do one step after the other, take a look at the intermediate `df`, and do *not* try to do many cleansing steps at once with an `apply()` function. If you have a messy dataset, maybe 10 steps are required, no way you can do all of that with a single `apply()` call.